# How to solve $\eta = \ln{\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}}$ for $\mu$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

In *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* by Christopher M. Bishop, he states that:

$$\begin{align}
\eta =& \ln\left(\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}\right) & (2.198) \\
\mu =& \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\eta}} & (2.199)
\end{align}$$

What are the steps to solve (2.198) for $\mu$ with the solution shown as (2.199)? Algebra is not my strongest skill and I clearly need more practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\eta = \ln\left(\frac{\mu}{1-\mu} \right)$$

$$e^{\eta} = \frac{\mu}{1-\mu}$$

$$e^{\eta} - \mu e^{\eta} = \mu$$

$$e^{\eta} = (1+e^{\eta})\mu$$

$$u = \frac{e^{\eta}}{1+e^{\eta}} = \frac{1}{e^{-\eta}+1}$$

Comment: I got that far but didn't see what I could do with it other than $(1-\mu)e^\eta = \mu$. What to do next eludes me (if this is the right path to go down in the first place).

Comment: @Matt, thanks for your comment that shows where you get stuck, I've updated the answer to show steps after yours.

Answer (score 1):

$$\eta = \ln{\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}}$$

$$e^{\eta} = e^{\ln{\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}}}$$

$$e^{\eta} = \frac{\mu}{1-\mu}$$

$$e^{\eta}(1-\mu) = \mu$$

$$e^{\eta}-e^{\eta}\mu = \mu$$

$$e^{\eta} = e^{\eta}\mu + \mu$$

$$e^{\eta} = (e^{\eta}+1) \mu$$

$$\mu = \frac{e^{\eta}}{e^{\eta}+1}$$

$$\mu = \frac{e^{\eta}}{e^{\eta}+1}\frac{\frac{1}{e^{\eta}}}{\frac{1}{e^{\eta}}}$$

$$\mu = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\eta}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The natural logarithm and exponential functions are inverses of one another, which means that

- $e^{\ln x} = x$ for $x > 0$, and
- $\ln(e^{x}) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So if we want to isolate $\mu$ we need to get it outside of the logarithm; we can do this by exponentiating both sides:

$$
\eta = \ln \left ( \frac{\mu}{1-\mu} \right ) \\
\Rightarrow e^\eta = e^{\ln \left ( \frac{\mu}{1-\mu} \right )} \\
\Rightarrow e^\eta = \frac{\mu}{1-\mu} \\
\Rightarrow (1-\mu)e^{\eta} = \mu \\
\Rightarrow e^{\eta} - \mu e^{\eta} = \mu \\
\Rightarrow e^{\eta} = \mu + \mu e^{\eta} \\
\Rightarrow e^{\eta} = \mu(1 + e^{\eta}) \\
\Rightarrow \frac{e^{\eta}}{1 + e^{\eta}} = \mu
$$
The final step is multiplying the numerator and denominator by $e^{-\eta}$ (this is the same as multiplying by 1 which doesn't change the value of the expression)
$$
\mu = \frac{e^{\eta}}{1 + e^{\eta}} \\
\Rightarrow \mu = \frac{e^{-\eta}\cdot e^{\eta}}{e^{-\eta}(1 + e^{\eta})} \\
\Rightarrow \mu = \frac{1}{e^{-\eta} + 1}.
$$